# background-image слайдер, как сделать плавность?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет!
Есть у меня JS код слайдера при помощи `background-image`.
Проблема в том, что он меняет изображения очень резко.

Помогите пожалуйста добавить плавность в это явление

```js
var bgArr = [
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000",
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/ff00ff",
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/cdfc11"
];
var i = 0;

// Start the slide show
setInterval(function() {
  $("#demo").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
  (i < bgArr.length - 1) ? i++ : i = 0
}, 2000);
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" style="text-align:center; 
          width:90%; 
          height:310px; 
          overflow:hidden; 
          border-style:dashed; 
          border-width:1px;">
  <p style="margin-top:83px;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Задай блоку `#demo`   `transition: all 1s;`

```js
var bgArr = [
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000",
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/ff00ff",
  "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/cdfc11"
];
var i = 0;

// Start the slide show
setInterval(function() {
  $("#demo").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
  (i < bgArr.length - 1) ? i++ : i = 0
}, 2000);
```

```css
#demo {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" style="text-align:center; 
          width:90%; 
          height:310px; 
          overflow:hidden; 
          border-style:dashed; 
          border-width:1px;">
  <p style="margin-top:83px;"></p>
</div>
```